# iterate over object properties fails?

Tags: javascript

I'm having the weirdest problem trying to use for( var i in object.property ) which immediately fails, yet Firebug shows me the object and it looks properly formed. I am able to iterate over objects all the time, and I can't tell what is different with this one.

here's the object as Firebug shows it. cTags is an object with a property "tags" which itself contains properties, each of which is an array:

Firebug trace output:

```
cTags.tags     Object { question=[2], template=[2]}
```

the keys to the "tags" property should be "question" and "template" and firebug shows them, if I expand the firebug trace of cTags.tags:

```
question     ["q1", "q2"]
template     ["Activity1", "Course Templates"]
```

yet when Firebug encounters my for in, it immediately dies, with no error, just skips out after this statement:

```
for( var i in cTags.tags ){     
    if( cTags.tags.hasOwnProperty(i)){
```

`i` is undefined after the first statement. Yet, I can even trace the hasOwnProperty function in Firebug:

```
 cTags.tags.hasOwnProperty("template")       true
```

I feel like I am missing something really dumb here, but what is it?  How could this fail, yet Firebug show me that it should be good to go?  What would cause `i` to be undefined?

[edit]

It's actually dying on the hasOwnProperty call.  So, how could that be when Firebug shows that it does indeed have those properties?

Comment: Something is going on that you're not showing us, how does  http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/jnjHK/ differ from what you're doing?

Comment: well, yes there is a lot going on, but nothing between the object definition and the for in statement. essentially jfiddle is the same. The object itself is returned from ajax and parsed by prototype.js.  Either way, I break on the for in statement, and firebug shows the object as I expect it to be, and iterating though that should be no problem. so I step into it, and it dies there.

Comment: OK, I ripped out the guts of the for in loop, and it's dying on  if( cTags.tags.hasOwnProperty(i)  it is actually executing the loop.  So what would make it die on the hasOwnProperty?

Comment: Try to reproduce it on jsfiddle.net, they have a JSON post-back feature that might be useful. If you can reproduce it in an isolated case then someone might be able to help.